# How can I show only comments with id equal to a certain id associated with a given page?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to write a basic "website discussion and sharing" app with Meteor and MongoDB. I'm very new to coding and this is just for my own edification. They way i've written it so far I can post comments on individual pages associated with shared websites but every comment shows up on every site page regardless of on which page the comment was made. I have made it so that the comments save with the siteId as their own Id so I would think this would be easy, but after 5 hours of fiddling and googling, I have not made any progress. I'll include the relevant code snippets below and would greatly appreciate any help!

in main.html I have this template...

```
<template name="discussSite">
    <h3>Discussing: {{url}} </h3>
    {{> addCommentForm}}

  {{#each comments}}
  <div class="comment" id={{siteId}}>
  <h4>{{text}}</h4>
  <h5>by {{createdBy}} on {{createdOn}}</h5>
  <h6>id: {{siteId}}</h6>

  </div>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

and in my events.js I have...

```
Template.addCommentForm.events({
 'click .js-add-comment':function(event){
     var comment_text = $('#comment_input').val();
     var user = 'anonymous person';
     var site = this;
     if (Meteor.user()){
         user = Meteor.user().emails[0].address
     }
     var comment = {"text":comment_text,
                    "siteId":site._id,
                 "createdOn":new Date(),
                 "createdBy":user};
    Comments.insert(comment);
     return false;
 }
});
```

Finally, in my helpers.js (which I know is where the bulk of the problem is. I don't quite understand how to use .find({}) commands and filters yet...

```
Template.discussSite.helpers({

'comments':function(siteId){

return Comments.find();

},

});
```

So to summarize, when I comment on site #1 it shows up, but the problem is that the same comment shows up under site #2 and site #3. How can I attach it to the site under which it was created and keep it there?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: This should help you https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html a "[selector]" is just a hash of the key and values of what you want to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper needs to filter the data like this by passing in this siteId:

```
Template.discussSite.helpers({
    'comments':function(siteId){
        return Comments.find({"siteId":siteId});
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense but all the comments disappear when I use it. New comments do not show up either...

Comment: figured it out. Thanks so much. I needed to use what you showed above but change siteId to this._id as follows:

    Template.discussSite.helpers({
        'comments':function(siteId){
            return Comments.find({"siteId":this._id});
        }
    });